# How do I create a responsive navbar with a logo, searchbox and links and still be responsive?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to achieve a two row navigation using BS 3, but I am having a hard time find out how to do it.  Every method I've tried has failed.  I would like to keep the markup as standard as possible. Here's what I want it to look like:

http://jsfiddle.net/technotarek/ePGa9/

The example uses old BS code. I can't seem to get it to work in BS 3.0.

Here's my attempt.  The logo is quite large, but I want it to scale accordingly.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/490x164&text=Logo" alt="My Logo"></a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <form class="navbar-form pull-right">

                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="search-box-text form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </form>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                <li><a href="/register" class="ico-register">Register</a></li>
                <li><a href="/login" class="ico-login">Log in</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: why don't you see this link. http://getbootstrap.com/migration/

Comment: The problem I am having that isn't addressed in the changes document is how to arranged these items so that they have the correct layout. Where do I put the rows and the columns. Some classes already have row and column attributes, but its hard to tell which one without tons of experimentation.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is here [BootstrapNavbarWithLogoSearchbarResponsive](http://jsfiddle.net/mr_eirenaios/ePGa9/221/)

html

---

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-default">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <img src="http://placehold.it/70x70">
</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="active"><a href="#">Active</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-header">Dropdown header</li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-8" placeholder="Search">
                        </form>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

css

---

```
    .navbar-brand {
float: left;
height: 10%;
padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is very close, but the two navbars are in the same row.